deploying libcrypto-3-x64.dll/legacy.dll gives an error 0xc0000142
I have written a GIS application in Qt installed in MSYS/MINGW64. The application uses GDAL. Normally I copy the exe and all relevant dlls into one packge for deployment which works fine. I just updated all libraries in MSYS and get error 0xc0000142 when trying to deploy the apllication, which traces back to libcrypto-3-x64.dll which uses legacy.dll which I believe is the problem.
I open a command window, change the path to c:\ and try to run the application. I get error 0xc0000142 unable to run. When I remove libcrypto-3-x64.dll and set the path in the command window to "c:\qt\msys64\mingw64\bin" where the dlls are installed, the application runs.
It appears that I can put all relevant ddls in the exe dircetory, except libcrypto-3-x64.dll which needs to be in c:\qt\msys64\mingw64\bin AND legacy.dll, which needs to be in c:\qt\msys64\mingw64\lib\ossl-modules.
I have tried other versions of openssl for this library but there are then other dependencies that start breaking, so that is almost unsolvable.
Is there a way to solve this?
Is this a bug?
part of the answer may be here: When using staticly linked OpenSSL 3.0.8 on some machine legacy provider can't be loaded

I just ran into the same problem with a GDAL application. Did you find a solution?

solution in windows is a workaround:
if your installation directory is: "../myapp/bin/something.exe"
do the following: "../myapp/lib/ossl-modules/legacy.dll"

It seems to, that the path to legacy.dll is hardcoded into libcrypto-3-x64.dll, but it can be overridden with OPENSSL_MODULES env variable.
So, if you have both dlls in your directory with your exe file, you can start it using a bat file like this:
set OPENSSL_MODULES=%CD%
program.exe


solution in windows is a workaround:
if your installation directory is: "../myapp/bin/something.exe"
do the following: "../myapp/lib/ossl-modules/legacy.dll"
